# how do you do a remember me or a stay signed in function with AngualarFire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

or using normal email and password method so that everytime i open the app i dont have to sign in. just go through..

```js
.controller('signupCtrl', function(taskref, $scope, $firebaseArray, $state, $firebaseAuth) {

      var fbref = $firebaseAuth(taskref);


      $scope.createUser = function() {
        taskref.$createUser({
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
          })
          .then(function(authData) {
              $state.go('settings');

            };

          })
```

with this sign in function with either googleAuth or email&password methods

```js
.controller('googleSignUpCtrl', function(taskref, $scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth, $state) {
  $scope.googleSignIn = function() {
    var authData = taskref.getAuth();

    taskref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) {

      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        taskref.child("users").child(authData.uid).once("value",           function(snapshot) {
          var ifExists = snapshot.exists();

          if (ifExists) {

            $state.go('tabsController.pendingTasks');
            console.log("user already exists");
          } else {
            $state.go('settings');
            $scope.authData = authData;
          }
        });
      }
    }, {
      remember: "sessionOnly",
      scope: "email"
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Use `$scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged()`. See the documentation for [retrieving authentication state](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#retrieving-authentication-state)

Comment: cool.. makes sense